# Renomear valores usando if else

Tags: php, jquery-datatables

Estou usando DataTable pra gerar uma tabela onde tem um campo Status que recebe valores 1 ou 2 sendo que Status com valor 1 é Ativo e 2 é Inativo. 
como faço pra mostrar Ativo/Inativo ao invés do nº.

Tente fazer if else aqui pra imprimir o resultado mas não consegui.

Esse trecho é onde faço array do Status: array( 'db' => 'status', 'dt' => 6),

obs. db é o resultado que vem do banco e dt é a coluna no datatable.

```
    $columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0),
    array( 'db' => 'empresa', 'dt' => 1),
    array( 'db' => 'ar',  'dt' => 2),
    array( 'db' => 'nf',   'dt' => 3),
    array( 'db' => 'tp', 'dt' => 4),
    array( 'db' => 'descricao', 'dt' => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d,$row ){
            return substr (($d), 0, 46);
        }
        ),
    array( 'db' => 'status', 'dt' => 6),


    array( 'db' => 'created','dt' => 7,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'd-m-Y - H:i:s', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array( 'db' => 'modified','dt' => 8,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'd-m-Y - H:i:s', strtotime($d));
        }
    )       

);
```

Desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: Não consegui localizar a coluna Status que você comentou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma função como fez para os outros campos se quiser pode usar um ternário para fazer a comparação ou if.

A diferença é que ele verifica se o valor for `1` é ativo qualquer outro é inativo. Já com o if você pode fazer uma comparação mais fina.

Outra alternativa é controlar isso com array. Caso novos status sejam adicionados eles viram elementos do array e não um novo if.

Ternário:

```
'formatter' => function($d, $row ){
            return $d == 1 ? 'Ativo' : 'Inativo';
        }
```

if:

```
'formatter' => function($d, $row ){
            if($d == 1) return 'ativo';
            else if($d == 2) return 'inativo';
            else return 'desconhecido';
        }
```

Array:

```
'formatter' => function($d, $row){
            $status = array(1 => 'Ativo', 2 => 'Inativo');
            return isset($status[$d]) ? $status[$d] : 'desconhecido';
        }
```